# MongoDB: mongod shows that my app is not authorized

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have installed mongodb and my mongodb and db folders are C:/mongoDB/bin and C:/data/db respectively. I have also setup admin user as stated on
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Now i want to perform basic CRUD operations requiring both read and write on a database mApp through Express and Mongoose. I am providing code for both app and schema below.

Code is well documented so that it is easy to understand.

App.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//Invoking user
var User = require('./schema.js');

//Creating an employee object by giving values to all properties
var User1 = new User({
  name: 'Anurag',
  username: 'Anurag2',
  password: 'abc',
  admin: false,
  location: 'somewhere',
  meta: {
    age: 25,
    website: 'abc.com'
  },
  createdAt: 'Jun 11 2017',
  updatedAt: 'Jun 11 2017'
}); //Remember to provide all records,otherwise document wont be saved.

//CRUD start. Creating a user document
User1.save(function(err, employ, num) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error occurred');
  }
  console.log('saved ' + num + ' record');
  console.log('Details ' + employ);
});

/* To retrieve documents from database, you can retrieve all at
   once, or one at a time by find(), findById(), findOne() */

//To retrieve all documents
User.find({}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error occurred while retrieving all docs');
  }
  console.log(data);
});

User.findOne({
  username: 'Anurag2'
}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error in finding one document');
  }
  console.log(data);
});

User.update({
  location: 'someplace'
}, {
  location: 'anything'
}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error in updating');
  }
  console.log('updated');
});

//update one document
User.findOneAndUpdate({
  username: 'Anurag2'
}, {
  admin: true
}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error in finding and updating');
  }
  console.log('updated' + data);
});

//Delete a user document
User.remove({
  location: 'anywhere'
}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error occurred');
  }
  console.log('removed');
});
```

DB Schema(schema.js)

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mApp'); //myApp is the database being connected here.


//now we open a connection
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Connected to Database');
});
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));

//initialising a schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird'); //used as mpromise was showing deprecated on console.


//creating a schema
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    Required: true
  },
  admin: Boolean,
  location: String,
  meta: {
    age: Number,
    website: String
  },
  createdAt: Date,
  updatedAt: Date
});

//creating a model that uses this schema
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

//now we export this model
module.exports = User;
```

Now, I login in mongo through admin and i changed the db to mApp. I run the app through node.

The mongod console shows I am not authorized to perform any actions on the app.

No query gets executed and I get all error messages. Why is this happening? Please help me with this.

Comment: add screenshot of mongod error in your question, to get detailed error

Comment: Also paste the command that was used to create the user credentials in Mongo.

Answer (score 1):

You have been enable authentication for your database.

So, you have to provide the corresponding credentials in your connection string

Change:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mApp');
```

To

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database');
```

[More information on mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

Comment: Did that. Now mongodb is telling me to connect through MongoClient.connect with auth credentials. Tried it, didn't worked
`var db=require('mongodb').Db;
var MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://myUserAdmin:abc123@localhost:27017/admin');



var db1=mongoose.connection;
db1.once('open',function(){
 console.log('Connected to Database');
});
db1.on('error',console.error.bind(console,'connection error'));`